# Build Qt5 from git - QWebKit framework is linked with absolute path

Tags: build, path, linker, qt5, otool

I just have build Qt5 on Mac 10.8 from git as per [this article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)

Everything went fine, I git `make`, `make install` and now I have Qt5 installed into `/usr/local/Qt-5.1.1`

The problem is that Assistant.app won't run - it crashes on startup. I ran otool (output is below) and found that QWebKit and QWebKitWidgets are linked with absolute path pointing to the build location which is no longer valida since I cleaned after installing. Is it a bug or something that I missed?

```
ak128@localhost:qt5 [git:stable+?]$ otool -L /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/bin/Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Assistant 
/usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/bin/Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Assistant:
    /Users/ak128/Developer/cpp/qt5/qtwebkit/lib/QtWebKitWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKitWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /Users/ak128/Developer/cpp/qt5/qtwebkit/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKit (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtSql.framework/Versions/5/QtSql (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtSensors.framework/Versions/5/QtSensors (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib/QtHelp.framework/Versions/5/QtHelp (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a genuine bug, see https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32417

As a workaround, you can set the DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH to point to your installation directory, in your case that would be:

```
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/lib
```

Then, you should be able to run assistant from command line, e.g.

```
open Assistant.app
```